# Multiple image sources in one image element

Tags: javascript, image

I'm quite new to Javascript (no jquery pls) and I'm trying to figure out if I can put multiple image sources in one image element

```
sadImages = document.createElement("img");
sadImages.src = "video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png";
sadImages.className = "projectImages";
sadScrollContainer.append(sadImages);
```

I would like to add a few more images from the sadness folder (not all!) without creating too many image elements.

I've tried writing it like

```
sadImages.src = "video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png" + "video/sadness/sadPhoto2.png";
```

and

```
sadImages.src = "video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png","video/sadness/sadPhoto2.png";
```

and

```
sadImages.src = ["video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png","video/sadness/sadPhoto2.png"];
```

but that doesn't work. It might be really stupid, but I'm trying to keep my code as short as possible.

Comment: Maybe concatenate them with a space? `sadImages.src = ["video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png","video/sadness/sadPhoto2.png"].join(" ")`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can`t create 1 image element with few images inside.

To not create images manually you can create array where store path to all your images and then just create img element for each path in your array

```
const images = 
['video/sadness/sadPhoto1.png','video/sadness/sadPhoto2.png']
images.forEach((img)=>{
    sadImages = document.createElement("img");
    sadImages.src = img;
    sadImages.className = "projectImages";
    sadScrollContainer.append(sadImages);
})
```

Comment: oooh okay thanks! Would have been useful if it was possible tho..

Answer (score 1):

[RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) perhaps srcset or sizes are useful

[Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) has example

```
<img srcset="sad-480w.jpg 480w,
             sad-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px"
 src="sad-800w.jpg"
 alt="sad">
```

Alternatively use JSON

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('img1').dataset.alternative))
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="sad1.jpg"  data-alternative='["sad2.jpg","sad3.jpg"]' />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate through a list of image sources, you will have to assign a data attribute to the image element. This can be achieves by accessing the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property.

```js
const createMultiImage = (sources, startingIndex = 0) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.className = 'multi-image';
  img.dataset.currentIndex = startingIndex;
  img.dataset.sources = JSON.stringify(sources);
  img.src = sources[startingIndex];
  return img;
};

const
  duration = 2000,
  container = document.querySelector('#container'),
  multiImage = createMultiImage([
    "http://placekitten.com/200/200",
    "http://placekitten.com/200/300",
    "http://placekitten.com/300/200",
    "http://placekitten.com/300/300"
  ]);

const
  incrMulti = (img, count) => {
    const
      sources = JSON.parse(img.dataset.sources),
      currentIndex = parseInt(img.dataset.currentIndex, 10),
      nextIndex = (currentIndex + count + sources.length) % sources.length;
    img.src = sources[nextIndex];
    img.dataset.currentIndex = nextIndex;
  },
  nextMulti = img => incrMulti(img, 1),
  prevMulti = img => incrMulti(img, -1), // Unused
  nextMultiAll = () => document.querySelectorAll('.multi-image').forEach(nextMulti);

container.append(multiImage);
setInterval(nextMultiAll, duration);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```